# Access Denied to SQL Server (through Excel VBA) when using SQL User without Login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having some trouble with my SQL Server Logons.  I'm building an Excel Spreadsheet that will retrieve data from an SQL Server (2008) and then display it in what ever way is required etc...

I have set up a SQL User without Login 'genericReadOnly' and 'genericReadWrite', it was my intention to then capture the windows login with environ("username") which will then retrieve what reports that person is allowed to access.  This was working fine whilst me and my team were working on it, but we are already set up on the SQL Server as 'Windows Users'.

I've now sent the file to someone who isn't also listed as a Windows User and it fails with `ACCESS DENIED FOR DOMAIN\USERNAME`, even though the connection string uses the genericReadOnly SQL Username.

Any ideas as I cannot add specific usernames for everyone that requires access.

Comment: post relevant code and connectionstring

Comment: This is just my guess you haven't provide enough information. But I think the database is set to just Windows Authentication mode (Which is the recommended mode, and these days most companies put this in their policy) As a result, the other person gets access denied. Your team because their ID have permission on database can run the app. If this is the case, best way would be to create a domain group, add   your users to the group and give permission on the database to that group.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a domain group and add that group as a windows login to SQL instance with the appropriate permissions.

Then add anyone that needs to use your Excel file just has to be a member of that group and requires no changes to your code or SQL setup.